# how to use which() in R, if I have too many query conditions?

Tags: r

I know, we can use which() function to subset the data frame according to the given condition.If I have a data frame(dat) with 5 columns and I need to find the mean of 5th column of the rows with w,x,y,z as their 1st,2nd,3rd and 4th column ,then I would do as this-

```
 myrows<-dat[which((dat[,1]==w)&(dat[,2]==x)&(dat[,3]==y)&(dat[,4]==z)),5]
 mean(myrows)
```

Now, if there are 50 such columns then I certainly cannot hard-code as this-

```
 myrows<-dat[which((dat[,1]==w)&(dat[,2]==x)&...&(dat[,49]==zz),50]
 mean(myrows)
```

Is there any other way, something like using a for loop like-

```
 for(i in 1:50)
 myrows<-dat[which(dat[,i]==x[i])]
```

I am a beginner in R, so please give an easiest way around this?

Comment: Please provide reproducible example and expected output so it's easier for others to help you. Have a [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info

Comment: There is no reason for using `which` here. R supports logical subsetting.

Comment: ["When first learning subsetting, a common mistake is to use `x[which(y)]` instead of `x[y]`"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a reference `data.frame` with one row, and the same columns as your `df` and then check row-wise for equality in all values like this:

```
reference <- data.frame(w, x, y, z)
mean(df[apply(df[,-5],1,function(x)all(x==reference)),5])
```

Comment: That solved it all.